# Spring Integration Kafka message-driven-channel-adapter receive message

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

For spring-integration-kafka version 2.1.0.RELEASE, [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_spring_integration.html) seems to be outdated

The example in the doc is incorrect as it doesn't match the constructor argument for **KafkaMessageListenerContainer**. Can somebody direct me how to create the bean correctly and corresponding Java code to process the message ?

```
<bean id="container1" class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg name="topics" value="foo" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that; we'll fix the docs; the correct documentation is in the [quick start section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_introduction.html#quick-tour).